# How do I set up Node/Express to act as a STUN server?

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc, stun

I'm looking for any good resources on the subject or maybe an open source project that implements a STUN server using Node/Express.

Comment: Can you be a bit for specific about what the problem is? Are you having any specific problems implementing this? n

Comment: Just asking for educational purposes @JorgeSilva

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STUN uses UDP, so you're not going to write a STUN server using Expess, which helps you build HTTP servers. An NPM search turns up a package called [stunsrv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stunsrv) that looks promising; C implementations are also available in the classic stund and stuntman.

Bear in mind that you need [two IP addresses](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stunsrv) to run a STUN server; if you can't manage that, you should probably make use of a public STUN server instead.

Comment: The second IP address of a STUN server is only needed if the client is doing NAT classification tests. Most VOIP, P2P, and ICE clients just need to do a simple binding request to the STUN server's primary IP:port to obtain a port mapping. Stuntman supports both single IP and dual IP listening modes.

Comment: @selbie true enough, but the software doesn't seem to care; it needs two addresses in its config to start up. Maybe a different server behaves differently.